# Split spark DF column of list into individual columns

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Interested in the scala spark implementation of this 
[split-column-of-list-into-multiple-columns-in-the-same-pyspark-dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49650907/split-column-of-list-into-multiple-columns-in-the-same-pyspark-dataframe)

Given this Dataframe:

```
|              X     |            Y|
+--------------------+-------------+
|                rent|[1,2,3......]|
|     is_rent_changed|[4,5,6......]|
|               phone|[7,8,9......]|
```

I want A new Dataframe with exploded values and mapped to my provided col names:

```
colNames = ['cat','dog','mouse'....]

|              Column|cat |dog |mouse |.......|
+--------------------+---|---|--------|-------|
|                rent|1  |2  |3       |.......|
|     is_rent_changed|4  |5  |6       |.......|
|               phone|7  |8  |9       |.......|
```

Tried:

```
val out = df.select(col("X"),explode($"Y"))
```

But its wrong format and i dont know how to map to my colNames list:

```
X              | Y |
---------------|---|
rent           |1  |
rent           |2  |
rent           |3  |
.              |.  |
.              |.  |
is_rent_changed|4  |
is_rent_changed|5  |
```

In the link above, the python solution was to use a list comprehension:

```
univar_df10.select([univar_df10.Column] + [univar_df10.Quantile[i] for i in range(length)])
```

But it doesn't show how to use a provided column name list given the column names are just the index of the columns.

Comment: Can you give out an example?
The explanation in the question seems unclear to me.

Comment: @VihitShah updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have come up with a solution which is based on certain assumptions.

1. Each array row will have the same number of elements.

2. We have the column names in an Array[String]

3. We know the expected number of values in the Array to be split into columns.

```
var df1 = df
```

where `df` is your input DF. For eg:-

```
+---+---------+
| id|    value|
+---+---------+
|  1|[A, B, C]|
|  2|[D, E, F]|
+---+---------+

val columns = Array("cat","dog","sheep")
```

`columns` is the array of column names.

```
for(i<-1 to columns.length)
df1 = df1.withColumn(columns(i-1),'value.getItem(i-1))


+---+---------+---+---+-----+
| id|    value|cat|dog|sheep|
+---+---------+---+---+-----+
|  1|[A, B, C]|  A|  B|    C|
|  2|[D, E, F]|  D|  E|    F|
+---+---------+---+---+-----+
```

You can now drop the value column if you want. Hope this works for you!

Comment: is there an extra quote at `'value.getItem(i-1))`

Answer (score 1):

Actually it's not as complicated.What dataframe's `select` expects, is just list of `Column` object and we can create that list programatically:

```
val columns = List("cat", "mouse", "dog")
   .zipWithIndex
   .map{ case (header, idx) => $"y"(idx).alias(header) }
```

Then only thing we need to do is just use it in `select`:

```
val df = List(("rent", Array(1,2,3)), ("is_rent_changed", Array(3,4,5))).toDF("x", "y")
df.select($"x" :: columns : _*).show()
```

Output:

```
+---------------+---+-----+---+
|              x|cat|mouse|dog|
+---------------+---+-----+---+
|           rent|  1|    2|  3|
|is_rent_changed|  3|    4|  5|
+---------------+---+-----+---+
```

Of course you could also inline it.

Comment: Just want to add, if i have an array instead of list, i should use `+:` instead of `::`